# How to add space in listing value in angular?

Tags: html, css, angular

As show below code i want to add space after every value in listing in angular. This data are come in table  view.

**In HTML file**

```
<ng-container matColumnDef="rType">
     <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef > Resource Type  </th>
     <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.rType}} </td>
</ng-container>
```

**In ts file**

```
bindTableCol() : void {
    if(DNHelper.loginUserData && DNHelper.loginUserData.resourcePreference1 && DNHelper.loginUserData.resourcePreference1.length > 0){
      this.displayedColumns = DNHelper.getColumnTable(DNHelper.loginUserData.resourcePreference1);
      this.displayedColumns.push('view_more');
      this.displayedColumns.push('action');
    } else {
      this.displayedColumns = ['divisonName', 'categoryName', 'rType', 'resourceStatus', 'view_more', 'action'];
    }
}
```

**In Result (These are values)**

```
CRWT1,CRWT2IA,CRWT2,CRWT3,ENG1
```

**Expected Result**

```
CRWT1, CRWT2IA, CRWT2, CRWT3, ENG1
```

**There snap of generated html**

[image]

Comment: you can something like `{{' ' + element.rType}}`

Comment: Thanks for suggestion but Not working.

Comment: can you share the generated html via a screenshot?

Comment: i share snap in code please check.

Answer (score 1):

To minimize the load on your application, you might also consider creating a pipe.

It could look something like this, as far as usage: `<p>{{ element.rType|join:', ' }}</p>`.

The transform function would look like this:

```
@Pipe({
  name: 'join'
})
export class JoinPipe implements PipeTransform {
  transform(input:Array<any>, sep = ','): string {
    return input.join(sep);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this :

```
<ng-container matColumnDef="rType">
     <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef > Resource Type  </th>
     <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.rType.split(",").join(", ")}} </td>
</ng-container>
```

Comment: It throw `ERROR TypeError: element_r19.rType.split is not a function`

Answer (score 0):

> Use this code It will help you.

```
<ng-container matColumnDef="rType">
 <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef > Resource Type  </th>
 <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.rType.replaceAll(',',', '}} </td>
</ng-container>
```

Comment: Its throw `ERROR TypeError: element_r19.rType.replaceAll is not a function` error